# Magento: registration and reset password error after installing SUPEE 6788

Tags: php, magento, reset-password

I am using magento 1.9.0.1.I am facing trouble in new customer registration and reset password  after installation magento SUPEE 6788. After Submitting register and reset password forms both pages just relaoded and shows a blank form. Please anyone help to solve this issue.

Comment: check your logs for error.

Comment: Your custom template forms need to be updated with the changes that the patch made to the base forms (FORMKEY). And as this is a Magento Admin question it really belongs over in magento.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to

`/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

AND

`/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Add this within the `<form>` tag of both pages (you may have them both or only 1 - just add it to the one that you have)

Comment: dear sulman , this code already present on these pages but error remains same.